# How do I change the alert color for tikz nodes in beamer?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

In Beamer I can change the color used for alerted text using the `\setbeamercolor` command. Changing the color, however, does not change the color used for tikz nodes to which I pass the `alert` option.

The following is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=green}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

Some \alert{text}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) {Node A};
\node[alert, below of=A] {Node B};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}    

\end{document}
```

The result is this:

[image: Node has wrong color]

Note that the color is correctly changed to green in the normal text, but that the tikz node ignores the color I chose and uses the default red.

How do I change the color used for nodes to which I pass the alert option? That is, how do I ensure that passing the alert option to node B makes it green?

Comment: @TeXnician Doesn't seem to work. I added the lines `\usepackage{xcolor}` and `\definecolor{alert}{rgb}{1,0,0}` and node B is still red.

Comment: Your version with `{rgb}{1,0,0}` defines red as `r` in `rgb` stands for red ;)

Comment: Oops! Yeah, I made a silly mistake there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by [Qrrbrbirlbel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16595/qrrbrbirlbel) in the comments, the most intuitive solution is actually to reuse the color as is by using the component access syntax on the beamer color like `alerted text.fg`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=green}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Some \alert{text}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) {Node A};
\node[text=alerted text.fg, below of=A] {Node B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}    

\end{document}
```

---

Alternative approach: you can adjust it as every other color. In this case f.i. using `\colorlet`.

[image: alert color]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=green}
\colorlet{alert}{green}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Some \alert{text}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) {Node A};
\node[alert, below of=A] {Node B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}    

\end{document}
```

Comment: It might be helpful that `alerted text.fg` is a valid color name that can be accessed with the usual means in PGF/TikZ.  That way, a template provided color doesn't need to be known.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel That's of course absolutely right, I'll edit the post.